# Selenium Webdriver get element (Python)

Tags: python, html, selenium, button, selenium-webdriver

I am making a bot that scrapes dictionary definitions. It first goes to this site: [LINE Dictonary](http://ce.linedict.com/#/cnen/home)

It then looks up the word "你好", and there following results show:
[image]

My goal is to have the bot click on the first result. However, how would I do that using Selenium Webdriver?

[image]

Here is a snippet of what the HTML looks like for the result. However, if you would like to see all of it, please go to LINE Dictonary's website and type in "你好". Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use [Waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) to do this, because you element was hidden, you can try this, it will work

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
driver.get("http://ce.linedict.com/#/cnen/search?query=%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="autocplt_wrap"]/ul[1]/li/span/a[1]'))
    )
    element.click()
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this XPATH :

```
//div[@id='autocplt_wrap']//descendant::span[@class='word']//a[text()='你好']
```

after searching for this : "你好" you can use this code :

```
asian_text= WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='autocplt_wrap']//descendant::span[@class='word']//a[text()='你好']")))  
asian_text.click();
```

**Note that** you can not use the **linkText** as there are **two** web Element present with same text between anchor tags.

Comment: upvote the answer, if you think this has helped you. Though you have already accepted the answer provided by zimdero , in which he has mentioned very absolute xpath which should be avoided as much as possible.